# 500 | Server Error - Laravel

Tags: laravel, http, composer

Criei um novo projeto em laravel com o comando `laravel new server`. Atualizei o composer, dentro do mesmo, com `composer update`.

Porém, ao accessar o `http://localhost:8000/`, ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> 500 |
>   Server Error

Estou utilizando windows. Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Veja qual erro está dando, no arquivo laravel.log, fica dentro de storage/logs, aí posta aqui que tento te ajudar! ;)

Comment: Cara, ele me retorna um conteúdo de 67 linhas. A primeira me diz isso: production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified.

Comment: Roda o comando `php artisan key:generate` pra gerar a chave

Comment: Agora isso: "ErrorException  : file_get_contents(C:\Users\Free\Documents\luiz\larang\server\.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory".
Conferi dentro do local, o .env não existe mesmo, somente o .env.example

Comment: O arquivo `C:\Users\Free\Documents\luiz\larang\server\.env` não existe.
Aconselho a ler a documentação de instalação do Framework, senão os comentários vão virar chat...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Umas das soluções foi acessar a pasta do projeto, via cmd, e rodar o seguinte comando:

```
copy .env.example .env
```

Isso, quando não se há o arquivo '.env' criado automáticamente na pasta, e, em seguida:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Depois, foi só rodar o `php artisan serve` normalmente.